# TFT screen to change sketches

Tags: arduino-uno, wifi, tft

I have an Uno + WiFi 101 thermometer and I'd like to be able to take it places and easily change WiFi network SSIDs and passwords.  Can I use a TFT screen to make these changes to a sktech or am I stuck using a PC and IDE for this kind of thing?

Can someone provide a sample sketch of what this might look like?  I want to know it's something that's possible before I spend the money on a TFT.

It's possible (let's face it, LIKELY) that I fundamentally misunderstand the capabilities and limitations of the TFT screen.  Sorry for the noobish question.

Comment: The screen is just a screen. You can do whatever you like with it.

Comment: So...you can use it to modify sketches and not just view output?

Comment: If that's how you've written your sketch.

Comment: That is encouraging.  I hope that someone can provide more detail.  My research continues.

Comment: All the TFT does is display things -- it's just a screen.  What Ignacio is saying is that if you have written your sketch to be able to modify itself, then you can use the screen to display a user interface.  The screen can't modify your sketch.  Your sketch technically can modify itself, but it is very difficult to do so and would require a custom bootloader.  It would be a lot easier to store the data that can be modified in EEPROM.

Comment: If you post that as the answer I'll close this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A TFT screen is just a screen. You can't modify SSIDs and passwords with it, any more than you can by poking your PC monitor (unless perhaps you have a touch-screen*). To modify things you would need:

- An input device (eg. a keypad)
- A method of displaying what you are entering (this is where the screen would be handy)
- A method of storing the new information. You could store things like passwords in EEPROM.
- Code to make all that work.

* Some distributors sell touch-screen interfaces designed to go on top of screens - this might conceivably be what you are thinking of. However you still need the touch-screen, and code to make the touch-screen, **and** the TFT screen, work.